# The difference of a output table generated by aggregation is keyedTable and keyedStreamTable

Tags: quantitative-finance, dolphindb

When the output table generated by aggregation is keyedTable and keyedStreamTable, the results are different
When the aggregation engine uses the tables generated by keyedTable and keyedStreamTable to receive the results, the effect is different. The former can be received, but it cannot be used as a data source for a larger period; the latter does not play an aggregation role, but only intercepts the first record of ticks data per minute.
The code executed by the GUI is as follows:

```py
barColNames=`ActionTime`InstrumentID`Open`High`Low`Close`Volume`Amount`OpenPosition`AvgPrice`TradingDay
barColTypes=[TIMESTAMP,SYMBOL,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DATE]
Choose one of the following two lines of code, and find that the results are inconsistent
///////////  Generate a 1-minute K line (barsMin01) This is an empty table

share keyedTable(`ActionTime`InstrumentID,100:0, barColNames, barColTypes) as barsMin01

////////  This code can be used for aggregation, but it cannot be used as a data source for other periods

share keyedStreamTable(`ActionTime`InstrumentID,100:0, barColNames, barColTypes) as barsMin01   

////////Choosing this code does not have an aggregation effect, and it is found that only the first tick of every minute is intercepted. 
//////////define the data sources 

metrics=<[first(LastPrice), max(LastPrice), min(LastPrice), last(LastPrice), sum(Volume), sum(Amount), sum(OpenPosition), sum(Amount)/sum(Volume)/300, last(TradingDay) ]>

////////////Aggregation engine
//////////// generate 1-min k line, Aggregation engine

nMin01=1*60000
tsAggrKlineMin01 = createTimeSeriesAggregator(name="aggr_kline_min01", windowSize=nMin01, step=nMin01, metrics=metrics, dummyTable=ticks, outputTable=barsMin01, timeColumn=`ActionTime, keyColumn=`InstrumentID,updateTime=500, useWindowStartTime=true)

/////////// subscribe and the 1-min k line will be generated

subscribeTable(tableName="ticks", actionName="act_tsaggr_min01", offset=0, handler=append!{getStreamEngine("aggr_kline_min01")}, batchSize=1000, throttle=1, hash=0, msgAsTable=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some diffenence between [keyedTable](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/k/keyedTable.html) and [keyedStreamTable](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/k/keyedStreamTable.html):

keyedTable: When adding a new record to the table, the system will automatically check the primary key of the new record. If the primary key of the new record is the same as the primary key of the existing record, the corresponding record in the table will be updated.

keyedStreamTable: When adding a new record to the table, the system will automatically check the primary key of the new record. If the primary key of the new record is the same as the primary key of the existing record, the corresponding record will not be updated.

That is, one of them is for updating and the other is for filtering.

The keyedStreamTable you mentioned "does not play an aggregation role, but intercepts the first record of ticks data per minute", is exactly because you set updateTime=500 in [createTimeSeriesAggregator](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/createTimeSeriesEngine.html). If updateTime is specified, the calculations may occur multiple times in the current window.

You use keyedStreamTable here to subscribe to this result table, so updateTime cannot be used. If you want to force trigger, you can specify the forceTrigger parameter.